# html to pdf using itextsharp how to set <div> element border

Tags: html, pdf-generation, itext

I am passing some **html** to to convert it to **pdf** using **itextsharp**.
I am using some div tag and want border around this tag in the pdf. I have used style property but didn't worked.. 
how can i do it..

Comment: To the best of my knowledge only the table elements support border properties. See this post for more information and an alternative: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329942/how-to-apply-style-while-writing-html-to-pdf

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried something like...

```
StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
css.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.DIV, HtmlTags.BORDER, "1");
```