# How to add border to DIV element, while generating PDF from HTML using iText?

Tags: html, border, itext

Is there any way to add border to DIV element, while generating PDF from HTML? Table cell is not an option, because it required three nested tags (table, tr, td), while I just need a border around text or image.

I've noticed that border feature for DIV is marked as "TODO:" in source code. Will it be included in nearest releases? If not, is there any workaround to add border to DIV?

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried something like...

```
StyleSheet css = new StyleSheet();
css.LoadTagStyle(HtmlTags.DIV, HtmlTags.BORDER, "1");
```

Source: [html to pdf using itextsharp how to set <div> element border](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8061333/html-to-pdf-using-itextsharp-how-to-set-div-element-border)

Comment: I have HTML page text at the input. I do not build it manually.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/6329942/how-to-apply-style-while-writing-html-to-pdf hope this helps

Comment: Thank you, I will look at WKHTML2PDF tool.

Answer (score 0):

> On android using itextg-5.5.9.jar with external .css file.
> (with XMLWorkerHelper).

itextg-5.5.9.jar is a subset of itext-5.5.9.jar.

> **DIV** does not work with borders.
>
> **td** **DOES** work with borders.

```
td
{
    border: 1px solid blue;
}
```

See:
http://demo.itextsupport.com/xmlworker/itextdoc/CSS-conformance-list.htm